# GeoFire warnings with Firebase 4.0 - Empty paragraph passed to '@return' command + other

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, geofire

I had zero warnings, then I updated to Firebase 4.0 now I have two warnings within GeoFire that won't go away.

**Warnings**

.../Pods/GeoFire/GeoFire/API/GeoFire.h:108:11: Empty paragraph passed to '@return' command

.../Pods/GeoFire/GeoFire/API/GeoFire.h:108:5: '@return' command used in a comment that is attached to a method returning void

**GeoFire Code**

```
- (void)removeKey:(NSString *)key withCompletionBlock:(GFCompletionBlock)block;

/**
 * Gets the current location for a key in GeoFire and calls the callback with the location or nil if there is no
 * location for the key in GeoFire. If an error occurred, the callback will be called with the error and location
 * will be nil.
 *
 * @param key The key to observe the location for
 * @param callback The callback that is called for the current location
 * @return <- WARNINGS GIVEN ON THIS LINE
 */
```

Does anyone have any information about this or at least how to silence safely. On attempt to remove comment it says GeoFire is locked for editing.